# mySQL - count the number of instances with the same value, for a different user

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a table, **ReadingList**, which consists of a few columns. For the sake of simplicity, lets call them:

- reading_id
- link_id_fk
- user_id_fk

`reading_id` is just an *AI* key. `link_id_fk` can exist multiple times (for each `user_id_fk`)

What I'm trying to do, is find the **top 10** `link_id_fk` values, that are stored by the most users.

Here is my rubbish attempt at it (I just get 145 returned, which I'm not sure where its getting that number - but its certainly not the number I was expecting :))

```
SELECT
  *,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM ReadingList
   WHERE link_id_fk = ReadingList.link_id_fk) AS total_saves
FROM
  ReadingList
WHERE
  user_id_fk IN ('test123', 'test2') AND
  link_id_fk > 0 AND deleted = 0;
```

an desired example output would be:

```
link_id_fk   total_saves 
12            3 
34            2 
56            1
78            1
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: @Strawberry - DDL?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1. Obviously, in this context, it helps if you simplify your problem to 'top 5', say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a `GROUP BY` in a subquery:

```
SELECT rl2.link_id_fk, rl2.nb_link
FROM (
  SELECT link_id_fk, count(*) as nb_link
  FROM ReadingList
  WHERE
    user_id_fk IN ('test123','test2')
    AND link_id_fk > 0 
    AND deleted = 0
  GROUP BY link_id_fk
) as rl2
ORDER BY rl2.nb_link DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Why do you need the subquery? You can just put `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` on that query.

Comment: @Barmar not quite ... at least in older versions, `ORDER BY`  / `LIMIT` trigger before `GROUP BY`, so you can't rely on this for this kind of query.

Comment: I've never heard of that, it must be a bug in really old versions. Normally you need to use a subquery if you want to do limiting before grouping.

Comment: I've been using MySQL for years without ever running into that problem.

Comment: @barman We're stuck on 5.0 MyISAM here... maybe it was a JPA issue but I had this problem a few weeks ago; sorting on a `GROUP BY` aggregated column didn't work. I'm playing safe ;)